# NGINX wrong configuration SSL certificate - The domain name does not match the certificate common name or SAN

Tags: ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate

I have an easy one, I think. I purchased a rapid SSL, I installed it on my website. It seems to be ok (I have a key file, the intermediate and final crs files), but there is a little mess: the SSL is correctly installed on https://xxxxx.com BUT NOT on https://www.xxxxx.com .

This is the error that I got from SSL checker:

```
Wrong certificate installed.
The domain name does not match the certificate common name or SAN.
```

I have a Nginx machine. This is a portion of config file:

```
server {
  listen 80; ## listen for ipv4
  listen 443 ssl;

  set $myHost "xxxx.com";
  set $site "xxxx";
  server_name  xxxx.com www.xxxx.com local.xxxx.com staging.xxxx.com s.xxxx.com;

  #ssl_certificate        /var/www/sites/ssl/oldfile.cert;
  #ssl_certificate_key    /var/www/sites/ssl/oldfile.key;
  ssl_certificate         /var/www/sites/ssl/122015/newfile.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key     /var/www/sites/ssl/122015/newfile.key;

  root /var/www/sites/xxxx/current/web/;

  access_log /var/www/sites/xxxx/current/app/logs/xxxx.com.access.log;
  error_log  /var/www/sites/xxxx/current/app/logs/xxxx.com.error.log;
```

....

When I got the key file, I set xxxx.com as domain name of course, because www was not allowed.

I need the SSL on www. Thanks for your help!!

M :)

Answer (score 0):

You need a separate SSL certificate for each domain.  You will then need to split your configuration for each domain into virtual hosts (nginx) and reference each individual SSL certificates for each domain you wish to use.